# Does anyone know what this means?

Tags: json

I was wondering what this means in a json api file. This was included in a schedule for some people.

`"start"=>"2017-10-09T04:29:46-05:00",`

Comment: @Yeager It was rolled back to the original version. You should never change your question so that it becomes totally different from the original because that would invalidate existing answers on your question. And _please_ never try to circumvent a time limit by doing something like that; time limits are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is the timestamp(date) in ISO 8601, it means - 09.10.2017 04:29:46 UTC -5:00